# How to do select based on a substring of a particular column in HiveQL and SQL?

Tags: sql, hive, substring, hiveql

I have a table in hive

```
S.no  Age  minutes  code  
 1     10   20     75081     
 2     11   114    75080      
 3     21   104    75180     
 4     31   124    75108    
 5     10   20     75083     
 6     11   114    75180    
 7     21   104    75180
```

I want to write an hivesql/sql query that gives ranked list of total minutes spoken based on the region i.e first 4 digits of code.
How should i go about it? I know that SUBSTRING() gives me the required cut, but I have not been able to go from there.

```
Select code, minutes as total  
from TableT   
where S.no > 1
group by code 
order by total
```

Edit: 
The ranked results based on first 4 digits of zipcode should look something like this

total  code

322(i.e 104+114+104)   7518
  154(i.e 20+114+20) 7508
124    7510

Comment: Please edit your question and provide desired results.  It is unclear what results you want.  Also, I removed the MySQL tag because the question is explicitly about Hive.

Comment: please see edited question, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hmmm.  I'm thinking you want this:

```
select substr(zip, 1, 4) as region, sum(minutes) as minutes,
       rank() over (order by sum(minutes) desc) as therank
from tableT
where s.no > 1
group by substr(zip, 1, 4)
order by minutes desc;
```

Comment: thank you Gordon Linoff . I think this is what i was looking for.

Comment: My data is partitioned based on year month and day , so I have the three columns specifying month date and year.  how do i edit the above query to query over a specific date range? 

I know sql If I have single date field I  could use 'select date BETWEEN yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy-mm-dd' or do a ' >=  <=',

Comment: @user4590025 . . .You make careful use of `year`, `month`, and `day`.  For a given date, you would use `where year = 2015 and month = 10 and day = 13`, for instance.

Comment: In you solution you have done `select substr(zip, 1, 4) as region`  . so towards the end should we not use `group by region ` as opposed to `group by substr(zip, 1, 4) `

Comment: @user4590025 . . . You can use `group by region`, I think.  I tend not to remember off-hand which databases allow aliases in the `group by` and which do not.